# Clear Carthage cache from Azure Pipeline

Tags: ios, azure, azure-devops, carthage

I am currently running Carthage dependency manager for iOS, and I am having a hard time clearing the cache when running it over Azure Pipeline. This is what I am calling to build all the dependencies for the project.

```
carthage bootstrap --platform ios --verbose --new-resolver --use-xcframeworks
```

I have tried removing the cache based on the logs as following:

```
/Users/*****/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit
```

However, it still grabs the cached version of the repo and fails. I have tried building the same project locally and it works and builds fine.
I have also tried to clean the workspace as part of the pool job, but still, it doesn't clean the cache.

Any help in this context is much appreciated.

Comment: Same Question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71487439/how-to-delete-an-azure-pipeline-cache-without-changing-cache-key