# How to delete an Azure Pipeline cache without changing cache key

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a task that creates a cache

```
- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'sonarCache'
    path: $(SONAR_CACHE)
    cacheHitVar: CACHE_RESTORED
  displayName: Cache Sonar packages
```

However, the cache got corrupted. So how do I run this pipeline while telling it to ignore any existing cache ?

For some reason, I cannot change the cache key `sonarCache`

Answer (score 3):

There's currently no way to do this.
Here is what [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops) says:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe failing the pipeline once will invalidate the existing cache